# Getting the database data to front view in laravel?

Tags: laravel

As it is quite easy to get data from database in admin panel,but the case is that how can i get/view those data to front view , front view contains the data from several table. Could you please help me  ? How can i manage those front pages easily ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#defining-controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways, but this is what I normally do.

Use a separate controller method (say index() HomeController)  for the frontpage, and create an array of all the variables with the data from database and pass it on to the page. Let's say our homepage has some slider images, some blog posts, and and our team section, then your HomeController would look something like this:

```
    class HomeController extends Controller 
    {
        public function index()
        {
         $data = [];  //your empty array
         $data['sliders'] = Slider::all();   //data from sliders table
         $data['posts'] = Post::all();      //data from posts table
         $data['teams'] = Team::all();      //data from teams table
         return view('frontend.index',compact('data'));
    }
```

Now you can access all these in your frontend blade (here index.blade.php) as such:

```
    @foreach($data['teams'] as $key=> $value)
     //your loop code
    @endforeach
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the wonderfull world of laravel this is super easy.  But first let me dive a into the structure of laravel a bit.

It all begins with the controller. In Laravel, Controllers a re meant to group assiociated request handling logic within a single class. A basic resource controller would look like this:

```
class DomainController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){} // list domains
    public function create(){} // show create form
    public function store(Request $request){ } // handle the form POST 
    public function show($id){} // show a single domain
    public function edit($id){} // show edit page
    public function update(Request $request, $id){} // handle show edit page POST
    public function destroy($id){} // delete a domain
}
```

Now how can you return the data to the view?
Let's say we want to generate a list of all users using the index function from the controller.

```
public function index()
{
 $users = User::all();
 return view('users.index', compact('users'));
}
```

With this return statement we will get a view and in that view we will have the $users variable available because of the use of the comapct function.

Now if we want to show a simple list:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<li>{{$user->name}}</li>
<li>{{$user->age}}</li>
@endforeach
```